# How to set a background color of a list in j2me

Tags: java, java-me, lcdui

I'm new in J2ME and I'd like to know how to make the background of my list to a color like grey and text into a color like black? The tutorials I'm getting are too complex for a beginner, I was wondering whether you guys might care to help.

Here is my code.

```
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

public class ExclusiveChoiceList extends MIDlet{
    private Display display;
    private List list;

    public ExclusiveChoiceList() {
      list = new List("Books", Choice.EXCLUSIVE);
    }

public void startApp(){
display = Display.getDisplay(this);
list.append("PHP", null);
list.append("MySQL", null);
list.append("JAVA", null);
list.append("VB.net", null);
list.append("Javascript", null);
display.setCurrent(list);
}
public void pauseApp() {}
public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional){
notifyDestroyed();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two ways:
**1**-You can use **LWUIT**.You can set Foreground color( The component foreground color that usually refers to the
component text color. For example, for a Button it's the text color) and 
Background color (The component background color) for each component(and so for lists).For example:

```
Button.bgColor=ff0000   
SoftButton.fgColor= ffffff
```

And you can use themes that creates manually or by **LWUIT Theme Creator**.
For more information about lwuit see [LWUIT_Developer_Guide.pdf](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/lwuit-1.3/LWUIT_Developer_Guide.pdf) and specially chapters 10,11.
**2**-On the other hand you can **extend a canvas** for your purpose.You can see a good tutorial and full source code [here](http://www.jappit.com/blog/2008/09/12/how-to-build-a-canvas-based-list-in-j2me/).
Second way is less time consuming

Answer (score 0):

I use J2ME Polish for GUI in Java ME Application. In J2ME Polish everything is based on case cade style sheet format like in website. There is a file called polish.css to define the style sheet.

I use following code in the polish.css for displaying background in list.

```
focused 
{
    background-color: #cccc;
}
```